# Permanently add key to ssh-agent and delete key from disk exactly like in Windows

Tags: linux, rhel, openssh, key-authentication, ssh-agent

In Windows, you can run ssh-agent as a service, permanently add ssh keys (per user), and then delete those key files from disk so they are no longer there at all. You cannot retrieve the key from the ssh-agent (or at least there is no indication that is possible or anyone has ever succeeded in doing so that I can find).

How do I accomplish exactly this in Rocky/RHEL/CentOS/etc.? Every answer I am finding talks about ssh-agent in Linux only housing those keys in memory, never persisted over a reboot, and that the keys must remain somewhere on the file system to be loaded every time.

I am hard-pressed to believe MS has done something with SSH that Linux cannot do in further hardening a system, and greatly hope someone can help me understand something I've missed.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing on windows. `ssh-agent` should work the same there, keeping the private key in RAM until the agent stops. Are you perhaps talking about the windows certificate store? Did you "install" your private key there?

Comment: Also, where do you think a private key should be if not in the filesystem? How is your machine supposed to read it after a reboot?

Comment: @Panki I have to administer systems of all types. I prefer Linux, but also work w/client Windows systems. I mean exactly what I say. In Windows ssh-agent is easily setup as an "always-on" service. I could accomplish in Linux as a systemd daemon. Difference is that an ssh-add of private key (supplying a password) in Windows permanently adds the private key for the ssh-agent in context of the current user. I can then delete private & public key files. After a reboot, I can still ssh to another machine that has pub key in authorized_keys, no password.

Comment: @Panki One comment mentioned ssh-agent on Win may store keys in the user registry, though I'm not sure how. My understanding is that while ssh-agent is able to perform signing, and keys can be deleted, there is no way to extract the key, so I'm guessing they are hashing/encrypting it separately, maybe like to keepass or similar. Either way, that persistence allows trivial operation that means I neither have to store the files directly on disk nor reference them in a path in a script that others can see anywhere.

Comment: @Panki On my Linux boxes, all my disks including root are encrypted, SELinux is enabled and used for everything, root is disabled, and a non-sudo account runs all containers through Podman. I like my security, and while I believe I've covered my bases, I'd still rather not have private keys sitting on a disk anywhere. Windows provides a way to do this. Can Linux?

Comment: [Apparently you're talking about this.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement) It says the private key will be stored "within a Windows security context, associated with your login" with no further details, so my first guess would be that the private key is stored within either `C:\Users\<username>\ntuser.dat` or `C:\Windows\system32\config\sam`, presumably encrypted using your Windows password as the encryption key.

Comment: @telcoM It's certainly possible, and I can appreciate to some degree why they haven't been explicit, even if generally I like to understand clearly what is going on.

But yes, either way, that functionality in Windows is incredibly helpful and greatly appreciated. Despite my time with Linux oddly my exposure setting up multiple system in a production environment like this was first through Windows, and instrumental establishing a very secure automated path between systems to a DMZ.

I want this level of security in all my Linux systems. How is that achieved?